# How to send var from ajax to submit of modal in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a php file that contains a bootstrap/ajax calendar with click action that open a modal bootstrap. This action send a var to the modal and when you click into submit modal button this save the var into mysql database with a php file called. My problem is that in the modal is showed the var correctly, but this isn't sended to php file to save into database.

This is my code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 ...
 eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {



            $('#createEventModalEdit #start').text(event.start);
            $('#createEventModalEdit #end').text(event.end);
            $('#createEventModalEdit #patientName').text(event.title);
            $('#createEventModalEdit #id').text(event.id);



            $('#createEventModalEdit').modal('show');
 ...

  $('#submitButtonEdit').on('click', function(e){
// We don't want this to act as a link so cancel the link action
e.preventDefault();

doSubmitEdit();
});

  function doSubmitEdit(){
$("#createEventModalEdit").modal('hide');
console.log($('#apptStartTime').val());
console.log($('#apptEndTime').val());
console.log($('#apptAllDay').val());
console.log($('#id').val());



        var title = $('#patientName2').val();
        var start = $('#apptStartTime').val();
        var end = $('#apptEndTime').val();
        var allDay = $('#apptAllDay').val();
        var idEvent = $('#id').val();
        alert(end);
$.ajax({
                url: 'process.php',
                data: 'type=changetitle&title='+title+'&eventid='+idEvent, **Here var idEvent haven't value. If I change this for exist id like: '25' is changed**
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response){
                    if(response.status != 'success')                            
                    revertFunc();
                },
                error: function(e){                     
                    revertFunc();
                    alert('Error processing your request: '+e.responseText);
                }
            });

alert("form submitted");

$("#calendar").fullCalendar('renderEvent',
    {


        title: $('#patientName2').val(),
        start: new Date($('#apptStartTime').val()),
        end: new Date($('#apptEndTime').val()),
        allDay: ($('#apptAllDay').val() == "true"),
    },
    true);
 }
```

And html modal bootstrap code:

```
 <div id="createEventModalEdit" class="modal hide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel1">Crear tarea</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<form id="createAppointmentForm" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputPatient">Tarea:</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" name="patientName2" id="patientName2" tyle="margin: 0 auto;" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" data-source="[&quot;Value 1&quot;,&quot;Value 2&quot;,&quot;Value 3&quot;]">
              <input type="hidden" id="apptStartTime"/>
              <input type="hidden" id="apptEndTime"/>
              <input type="hidden" id="apptAllDay" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="start">Inicio:</label>
        <div class="controls controls-row" id="start" style="margin-top:5px;">
             </div>
            <label class="control-label" for="end">Fin:</label>
        <div class="controls controls-row" id="end" style="margin-top:5px;">
        </div>

        <label class="control-label" for="start">Inicio:</label>
        <div class="controls controls-row" id="id" style="margin-top:5px;">
             </div>

    </div>
</form>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitButtonEdit">Save</button>
</div>
```

What I doing bad?? How can assign correctly the value into idEvent?

Thanks!

Comment: i cannot see an input with the id=id, change it to input or get the value with $('#id').html()

Comment: when you execute the ajax, it goest to ``error`` or to ``success`` ??

Comment: I get success when execute ajax, but not insert...

Comment: I try get the value with $('#id').html() and this is correct, but not execute the refresh ajax code. I need push F5 to refresh..